# typeerror 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, typeerror

Here's the code:

```
The_Start = [1,1]
The_End = [1, 1]
for z in range(20):
    for x in range(len(The_Start) - 1):
        y  = The_Start[x] + The_Start[x + 1]
        The_End.insert[x + 1, y]
    print The_End
    The_Start = The_End
    The_End = [1, 1]
```

This code is supposed to make a Pascal's triangle. The error is on the sixth line.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to change the brackets in `The_End.insert[x + 1, y]` to parenthesis.

```
The_End.insert(x + 1, y)
```

It's good practice in Python to use lowercase variable names. Uppercase is generaly used for classes.

Answer (score 17):

You need parenthesis instead of `[]`:

```
The_End.insert(x + 1, y)
```