# Can anyone help me with this TypeError I keep getting in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, typeerror

I am trying to make a program that converts a 5 letter string typed in by the user into a float using values stored in a dictionary to convert each letter. This is my code:

```
    kvalues = {"a":1.01, "b":1.02, "c":1.03, "d":1.04, "e":1.05, "f":1.06, "g":1.07, "h":1.08, "i":1.09, "j":1.10, "k":1.11, "l":1.12, "m":1.13, "n":1.14, "o":1.15, "p":1.16, "q":1.17, "r":1.18, "s":1.19, "t":1.20, "u":1.21, "v":1.22, "w":1.23, "x":1.24, "y":1.25, "z":1.26}
    def convert_key(key):
        #converts the key into a float using the values stored in kvalues
        k1 = float(kvalues.get(key[0]))
        k2 = float(kvalues.get(key[1]))
        k3 = float(kvalues.get(key[2]))
        k4 = float(kvalues.get(key[3]))
        k5 = float(kvalues.get(key[4]))
        print k1 + k2 + k3 + k4 + k5
    convert_key(raw_input (Please enter a key:))
```

When I run my program I get this error: "TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '**getitem**'". The really confusing part is when I run the code through the idle shell like this:

```
    key = "koala"
    kvalues = {"a":1.01, "b":1.02, "c":1.03, "d":1.04, "e":1.05, "f":1.06, "g":1.07, "h":1.08, "i":1.09, "j":1.10, "k":1.11, "l":1.12, "m":1.13, "n":1.14, "o":1.15, "p":1.16, "q":1.17, "r":1.18, "s":1.19, "t":1.20, "u":1.21, "v":1.22, "w":1.23, "x":1.24, "y":1.25, "z":1.26}
    k1 = float(kvalues.get(key[0]))
    print k1
```

It works perfectly! Does anyone know what the issue here is? I'm new to Python and not too familiar with the nuances of the language.

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "K:\Projects\koala.py", line 73, in <module> menu() 
File "K:\Projects\koala.py", line 10, in menu encrypt() 
File "K:\Projects\koala.py", line 28, in encrypt e_key = convert_key(e_key) 
File "K:\Projects\koala.py", line 67, in convert_key k1 = float(kvalues.get(key[0]))
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'getitem'
```

When print is added to the start of the function:

```
    <built-in method lower of str object at 0x0000000002AC7E40>
```

Comment: Show your actual code, not what you think the code should look like.

Comment: That is directly copied from my code.

Comment: Is there any other parts of the code you are't showing?  When it gives you the `TypeError`, it also gives you a line number and shows the line of the code with the issue with an arrow pointing to the spot with the problem.  Can you help narrow down the location of the actual problem using this information?

Comment: @user3052634 please provide the full traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\Projects\koala.py", line 73, in <module>
    menu()
  File "K:\Projects\koala.py", line 10, in menu
    encrypt()
  File "K:\Projects\koala.py", line 28, in encrypt
    e_key = convert_key(e_key)
  File "K:\Projects\koala.py", line 67, in convert_key
    k1 = float(kvalues.get(key[0]))
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Is there a way I can format that to look less... dense?

Comment: I copied the traceback to the original post (When someone asks for the traceback, the *always* want it in the post, not as a comment.)

Comment: Clearly, this is a snippet from a larger project, and somewhere you are naming some other function or object `kvalues` and shadowing (overwriting) the dictionary `kvalues`.

Comment: what you posted works (except you forgot "" around the question-string). You have to enter at least five characters when running it.
So are you sure that this is the part of your code that is causing the error? I see no calling of attribute get item …
Search for `getitem` in your project, it looks like you wrote but did not call a function

Comment: You should check out this website: http://sscce.org/  It will help you create a bit of code that will help us debug the problem here.

Comment: @SethMMorton: I think the problem is with `key`, not `kvalues`.  If `kvalues` had been rebound to some builtin, I think we'd have seen an `AttributeError` on `.get`.  I think it's the `key[0]` which is giving the `TypeError`.

Comment: I can post the entire code if you want, I'm just not sure how to go about doing that. Its pretty long.

Comment: @DSM Yup, you are completely correct!  In that case, `key` is probably something that is not iterable.

Comment: So I should change key to something else?

Comment: @user3052634 That's why I pointed you to http://sscce.org/

Comment: @user3052634 What are you passing to your function (i.e. what is `e_key`?) I think that is your issue.

Comment: @SethMMorton I tested this, took a builtin function and wanted to get the first value `len[0]` but the error looks still different: `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable` .so I think it has to be another part

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075632/typeerror-builtin-function-or-method-object-has-no-attribute-getitem.  Did you accidentally do something like `e_key = float` or `e_key = str` or `e_key = int`, or `e_key = sum` or `e_key = len`?

Comment: @koffein: I think `len[0]` returns the `__getitem__` message in Python 2.  It returns the `not subscriptable` in Python 3.

Comment: I changed every instance of key to pass and still got the exact same error. This time it specifically pinpointed the error (or maybe it did that before and I didn't notice):  *def convert_pass(pass):*

Comment: Do us and yourself a favor.  Add `print key` as the first line of your function and rerun it.  Then add as part of the original question what is printed to the screen.

Comment: The (pass) was highlighted as the problem.

Comment: That's because `def convert_pass(pass):` is a separate and different issue.  `pass` is a reserved keyword and putting it as the variable to a function is illegal.

Comment: Please go back to the way the code was before, and add the `print key`.  Really, that will help us debug *so quickly* we should have suggested that first.

Comment: Changed it all to koala. If koala is something already used by Python, then I'm done using Python. As requested, Seth, I added `print koala` to the start of the function and will add the result to the question.

Comment: No no... I meant `def convert_key(key): print key; k1 = float(kvalues.get(key[0])); etc...`

Comment: I added an answer based on the `print` output.  I told you we should have asked for that first!

Comment: @DSM You are right, tested it in self-compiled python2.7 and OS X 10.8 standard python : different errors… nice to know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that somewhere you were doing this:

```
e_key = mystring.lower
```

When you meant to do this:

```
e_key = mystring.lower()
```

`.lower` is a *method*, meaning it needs to be called like a function, so you need the parentheses.  In the first method you simply reassigning the method to the `e_key` variable.

Comment: Oh my god. Wow. Kudos to you sir.

Comment: I recommend peppering your code with `print` when debugging, because what you expect your variables to contain may not always be the case (as you found out here).

Comment: +1 on `print`: `print(type(obj), repr(obj))`, or something similar, should always be one of the first moves.