# Creating a (2,2,3) Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm simply trying to create a `(2,2,3)` Numpy array, and have done the following:

```
a = np.array[[[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6]],
             [[6,7,8],
              [9,10,11]]]
```

I however get the following error:

```
File "xyz.py", line 6, in <module>
    [9,10,11]]] 
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot parens. You want

```
a = numpy.array([[[1,2,3],
          [4,5,6]],
         [[6,7,8],
          [9,10,11]]])
```

You got the "no attribute '__getitem__'" error because putting square brackets after a symbol means "call this object's __getitem__() method with the stuff inside the brackets", this is what's happening when you do a simple dictionary lookup:

```
>>> a = {1: 2}
>>> a[1]
2
>>> a.__getitem__(1)
2
```

Comment: Please consider not giving full answers to blatant typos. While such questions are on topic, they are only helpful for the asker and don't help future readers. These questions don't have to stay on the site once answered, but leaving upvoted/accepted full answers hinders [automatic deletion processes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/). There are also a lot of [dupes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075632/typeerror-builtin-function-or-method-object-has-no-attribute-getitem) for this error.

Comment: *parentheses :)

Comment: @AndrasDeak I was in the process of adding a more full explanation for the confusing error message while you were commenting. I disagree that this answer would be unhelpful for future askers, since the error is quite misleading.

Comment: See my edit to the comment regarding a duplicate. Again a reason not to answer.

Comment: How would you expect a future reader with the same syntax error to actually find this question? Which Google search terms would they use?